# Apache mpm for a social networking site

Tags: php, apache, social-networking

I am trying to build a social networking website that would have a large amount of users logged in at the same time, with an upper limit of around 5000 at a time.

I plan to use the LAMP stack. Apache can have 2 mpms (multi processing modules) - preforker(forks a new process per request) and the worker model (which uses threads per request).

Considering that my server side code is in PHP, and I want to be able to scale up the website on demand, which one would be more preferable. Some third party PHP modules we are using are not thread safe, so ideally preforker is recommended.

1. Is there any way by which delay between swapping processes can be decreased in  preforking
2. Is there any way by which I can use the worker module, with php as well ?

Social networking sites running on the LAMP stack, normally use which mode?

Comment: Try https://www.howtoforge.com/configuring_apache_for_maximum_performance

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to server push services, apache is not a good choice. Take a look at [cherokee](http://cherokee-project.com) and [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/), both work much better with [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org) than mod_php with apache2, since you do not need CGI support (only FastCGI is supported with cherokee and nginx) only PHP.

A few weeks ago [I migrated my WordPress network from apache2-mpm-itk with mod_php to nginx+php5-fpm](http://petermolnar.eu/sysadmin-blog/wordpress-3-0-network-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-backend-on-ubuntu-11-04-server/). As a result system load drastically dropped, memory load became predictable and the user experience seems to be a lot faster. I also added some free test from [loadimpact.com](http://loadimpact.com), the serving times were better with the new config also.

Answer (score 0):

Apache isn't preferred with so much requests. You'd be better off with nginx for example. http://nginx.net/

"10000+ concurrent connections per server" sounds good enough ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache in worker mode if you do not use PHP with mod_php. Use PHP in Fastcgi mod, php-fpm is a must-try for that.

With current apache stable version (2.2) you will have problems if you want to use it in chrooted mode. But you may try apache 2.3 or wait for the 2.4 and use mod_proxy_fastcgi instead of mod_fastcgi or others. You could also test the new event basef mpm with this version of Apache. Or of course you could try the other web servers as answered by @petermolnar